# Synchronisation of Two Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I have two threads in c#.. Now i need to wait for a particular statement to be executed before I can continue execution in the other thread which obviously is a case of synchronisation.
Is there any code that can carry this out as in using an in-built method?

This is the code example:

```
    public void StartAccept()
    {
            try
            {
                newSock.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(Accepted), newSock);
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in arguments while using begin-accept", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("socket closed while using begin-accept", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (SocketException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error accessing socket while using begin-accept", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid operation while using begin-accept", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception occurred while using begin-accept", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

    }
```

This receives data from the desired host which is selected by the code:

```
    private void listBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        String data = (String)this.listBox1.SelectedItem;

        ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(data);

        clientIP = new IPEndPoint(ip[0], 5555);

        newSock.Bind(clientIP);
        newSock.Listen(100);

    }
```

So in order to start receiving data I need to initialise the socket to the particular remote host which is done when i click on one of the hosts shown in the listbox.
For this I need the synchronization.

Comment: Apologies, I'd missed that in the question.

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) and [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx). They are signals that makes synchronisation between threads possible.

The first thread that needs to wait for something to get done will do myEvent.[WaitOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd.aspx)(), which blocks until the other thread calls myEvent.[Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.set.aspx)().

Let's say we have two threads, where one of them needs to do some kind of initialisation before the other thread can continue. You then share a AutoResetEvent between the two, let's call it myEvent.

```
// Signal example

using System;
using System.Threading;

class MySync
{
    private readonly AutoResetEvent _myEvent;
    public MySync(AutoResetEvent myEvent)
    {
        _myEvent = myEvent;
    }

    public void ThreadMain(object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting thread MySync");
        _myEvent.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine("Finishing thread MySync");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutoResetEvent myEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        MySync mySync = new MySync(myEvent);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(mySync.ThreadMain);
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        myEvent.Set();
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to continue...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Finishing");
    }
}
```

Don't confuse this with a shared resource where the access order doesn't matter. For example, if you have a shared list or a shared dictionary you need to wrap it in a mutex in order to guarantee that they execute correctly.

```
// Mutex example

object mySync = new object();
Dictionary<int, int> myDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

void threadMainA()
{
    lock(mySync)
    {
        mySync[foo] = bar;
    }
}

void threadMainB()
{
    lock(mySync)
    {
        mySync[bar] = foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for anwswering the question that was asked, not one you imagined . . . like what I did . . .

Comment: ok.. So with the same format of the code, if my method startAccept() must wait for the event listBox1_Click(Object Sender, EventArgs e) to be executed what would the code look like?.. I am somehow not being able to understand what myEvent would correspond to.

Comment: @Awik: If you edit your question above to include some concrete code examples it would be easier to give you a more precis answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an AutoResetEvent.

In the following example two methods get called by different threads and DoSomethingA() will be executed and finish before DoSomethingB() starts:

```
AutoResetEvent resetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);

void ThreadWorkerA()
{
    // perform some work
    DoSomethingA();

    // signal the other thread
    resetEvent.Set();
}

void ThreadWorkerB()
{
    // wait for the signal
    resetEvent.WaitOne();

    // perform the new work
    DoSomethingB();
}
```

Note: remember to dispose the AutoResetEvent :)

Answer (score -2):

Java has something called Join. I suspect there will be a predefined method in C# too.

Comment: join waits until a thread terminates, not a particular statement